# flash player debugger plug-in failure across all browsers

Tags: flash, debugging, plugins

I have been developing a flash web app for the past few months and using flash debugger to debug. Now all of a sudden, across all browsers i get a plug-in failure for the debugger only. Regular flash player plug in works and i've uninstalled and reinstalled multiple versions. Started happening after i set chrome from internal flash player plug-in to debug version so i can debug on chrome browser. Not sure why that would cause a problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Use the Flash Player uninstaller util: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html#main_Download_the_Adobe_Flash_Player_uninstaller
- Restart
- Search your computer for flashplayer.exe and delete them.
- Download and install the latest debug runtimes at: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
- Try is now.

You might also want to update your video card drivers and reboot. Since Flash 11 works very closely with the GPU, video card drivers can cause issues now.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention this is for mac osx.